# My Listview Returns nothing while using retrofit

Tags: android, listview, retrofit

I  am new to retrofit,i am just trying to json parsing, i don't know what i missed?

The list view is not displaying. Kindly help me with issue.I am using ListAcivity with List Adapter.This is Strange to me .Please help with this.
This is Client.java

```
public class UtubeClient {
private static UtubeApiInterface UtubeService;

public static UtubeApiInterface getTwitchTvApiClient() {
    if (UtubeService== null) {
         RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                .setEndpoint("http://tamilpasanga.in")
                .build();

        UtubeService = restAdapter.create(UtubeApiInterface.class);
    }

    return UtubeService;
}

public interface UtubeApiInterface {
    @GET("/mytuts/list.json")
    void getStreams(  Callback<List<UtubeChannel>> callback);
}
```

}

Get the callback in mainActvity

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

//private ProgressBar mProgressBar;



private List<UtubeChannel> streamData;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    streamData = new ArrayList<UtubeChannel>();

   // mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);



    setListAdapter(new MobileArrayAdapter(this,streamData));

    downloadDatainRetrofit();


}





private void downloadDatainRetrofit() {


       // mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        UtubeClient.getTwitchTvApiClient().getStreams(new Callback<List<UtubeChannel>>() {
                                                          @Override
                                                          public void success(List<UtubeChannel> utubeChannels, Response response) {
                                                          streamData.addAll(utubeChannels) ;
                                                          }

                                                          @Override
                                                          public void failure(RetrofitError retrofitError) {
                                                              //
                                                          }


                                                      }
        );
    }
}
```

UTubeChannel.java

```
      public class UtubeChannel {
private  String url;
private  String name;
     UtubeChannel(String url,String  name){
 this.url=url;
 this.name=name;
   }


public String getUrl()
{
    return this.url;

}
public  void setUrl(String url)
{
    this.url=url;
}

public String getName(){
    return  this.name;
}
public void setName(String name){
    this.name= name;

}
```

}

Mobile Array Adapter

```
public class MobileArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<UtubeChannel> {
protected static final String TAG = null;
private final Context context;

String outFileName;
private LayoutInflater inflater;







public MobileArrayAdapter(final Context context, List<UtubeChannel > objects) {
    super(context, R.layout.listview_item, objects);
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    this.context = context;





}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View rowView, ViewGroup parent) {


    ViewHolder holder = null;
    if (rowView == null) {

        rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_item, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.name = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        holder.url = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.url);



        //  viewHolder.button.setTag(viewHolder.text);
        // viewHolder.text.setTag(viewHolder.button);


        rowView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();


    }





   UtubeChannel channel= getItem(position);

    holder.name.setText(channel.getName());
    holder.url.setText(channel.getUrl());




    return rowView;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    public TextView url;


    public TextView name;



}
```

}

Comment: post `MobileArrayAdapter`

Comment: try debug your code and find size of `objects` in constructor of `MobileArrayAdapter`

Comment: @shayanpourvatan can u  explain what is the exact problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you passed empty list to your adapter, then you have tried download data from Internet but as you don't call, notifyDatasetChanged your list not showing anything. so you need change your code too :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    streamData = new ArrayList<UtubeChannel>();

   // mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    downloadDatainRetrofit();

}





private void downloadDatainRetrofit() {


       // mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

 UtubeClient.getTwitchTvApiClient().getStreams(new Callback<List<UtubeChannel>>() {
 @Override
 public void success(List<UtubeChannel> utubeChannels, Response response) {
       streamData.addAll(utubeChannels) ;
       setListAdapter(new MobileArrayAdapter(this,streamData));
 }

 @Override
 public void failure(RetrofitError retrofitError) {
                                                              //
 }


 });
}
```

or you can use:

1 - create one global value in your class as:

```
MobileArrayAdapter adapter.
```

2- in onCreate use:

```
adapter = new MobileArrayAdapter(this,streamData);
setListAdapter(adapter);
```

3- after downloading data use:

```
adapter.notifyDatasetChanged();
```

for refreshing list data

Comment: Thanks dude but i have tried like this,may i know its not working?  
        downloadDatainRetrofit();

        setListAdapter(new MobileArrayAdapter(this,streamData));

Comment: you have tried witch one? did your data comes correctly form internet?

Comment: ya i called DownloadinRetrofit() before list adapter like vice versa what i wriiten in the main activity